# Show base64 img gives The string contains invalid characters

Tags: javascript, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I´m trying to show a base64 image which I get from the camera plugin (iOS, ionic 3). I need the base64-Format because I need it for an REST-API-Call. 
After starting the takePicture-Function I get

```
The String contains invalid characters
```

I´ve decoded the *imageData*-String in an Tool and it´s valid.

**JS**

```
image: string = '';
base64Image: string = '';
base64Data: string[] = [];
_images: boolean = false;
...

takePicture() {

        const options: CameraOptions = {
          quality: 100,
          destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
          encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
          allowEdit: true,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
          correctOrientation: true
        }

        this.camera.getPicture(options)
        .then((imageData) => {
         let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
         console.log(base64Image);
         this.base64Data.push(imageData);
         this.image = base64Image;
         this._images = true;
        }, (err) => {
         // Handle error
         console.log(`ERR -> ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
        });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="_images">
    <img [src]="image | safePipe: 'html'" #imageResult />
</div>
```

**safe-html-Pipe**

```
...
public transform(value: string, type: string = 'html'): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
        case 'html': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
        case 'style': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
        case 'script': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
        case 'url': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
        case 'resourceUrl': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
        default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure what `imageData` is but why do you need this concatenation? `let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData`. `imageData` should have the header already. Anyway from the looks of it you'd also have to encode the string: `let base64Image = 'btoa(data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData)`

Comment: imageData has no header included. It´s only the base64 string. see https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/